# use mdc sass files in angular-cli projects

Tags: css, sass, angular-cli, sass-loader, mdc-components

I have a project using `angular-cli`. I am using [mdc components](https://material.io/components/web/catalog/)/. I want to import individual component's sass files. For this,

1) I have changed the default styleExt using this command

```
ng set defaults.styleExt scss
```

2) Renamed the file `style.css` to `style.scss`.

3) In `angular-cli.json` changed

```
"styles": [
        "styles.css"
      ],
```

to

```
"styles": [
        "styles.scss"
      ],
```

4) Added `stylePreprocessorOptions` configuration to include path

```
"stylePreprocessorOptions": {
        "includePaths": [
          "node_modules"
        ]
 }
```

5) Finally in `style.scss` file imported

```
@import '~@material/button/mdc-button';
```

but this is showing

```
ERROR in ./~/css-loader?{"sourceMap":false,"importLoaders":1}!./~/postcss-loader?{"ident":"postcss"}!./~/sass-loader/lib/loader.js?{"sourceMap":false,"precis
ion":8,"includePaths":["D://SK//Study//Material//MaterialWithAngularDemo//src//node_modules"]}!./src/styles.scss
Module build failed:
undefined
^
      File to import not found or unreadable: @material/theme/mixins.
Parent style sheet: D:/SK/Study/Material/MaterialWithAngularDemo/node_modules/@material/button/mdc-button.scss
      in D:\SK\Study\Material\MaterialWithAngularDemo\node_modules\@material\button\mdc-button.scss (line 17, column 1)
 @ ./src/styles.scss 4:14-187
 @ multi ./src/styles.scss
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a mistake in `includePath` instead of `node_modules` it should be `../node_modules`.

```
"stylePreprocessorOptions": {
        "includePaths": [
          "../node_modules"
        ]
 }
```

After changing this, it is working fine.